# merge lists in python adding elements repeated

Tags: python, list, append

I have a question, I have two files, each of them have two columns, one is T and the second column a function depending on T. I want to merge them, and write them both in an output file, for that I am using the following (For some reason using just T = T1+T2 didn't work and that's why I'm using extend).

```
T1 = column1_of_file1
Y1 = column2_of_file1
T2 = column1_of_file2
Y2 = column2_of_file2

Total_T = []
Total_Y = []
Total_T.extend(T1)
Total_T.extend(T2)
Total_Y.extend(Y1)
Total_Y.extend(Y2)
```

The problem I have is that there are elements in T1 that are the same to the ones of T2. T1 starts with 1 and finishes in 4, I'm listing below the last 7 elements of both columns:

```
# T1       Y1
 ...        ...
3.76    -25.8529    
3.80    -25.8474   
3.84    -25.8422  
3.88    -25.8356  
3.92    -25.8286  
3.96    -25.8133 
4.00    -25.7997
```

And T2 starts with values 3.80 and runs to 8, but the corresponding 
values for Y2 are different:

```
#T2        Y2
3.80    -25.7331
3.84    -25.0383
3.88    -24.4059
3.92    -23.8288
3.96    -23.3027 
4.00    -22.8242  
4.04    -22.3917 
...       ...
```

What I want is to merge both lists removing the repeated elements in T
(which I know how to do just a for T1 in T2 remove) but since the values
in Y are different I want to add them up, so that in the end T_total and 
Y_total look like:

```
#T_total    Y_total
3.80        Y1[3.80] + Y2[3.80] 
3.84        Y1[3.84] + Y2[3.84]
3.88        Y1[3.88] + Y2[3.88]
3.92        Y1[3.92] + Y2[3.92]
3.96        Y1[3.96] + Y2[3.96]
4.00        Y1[4.00] + Y2[4.00]
```

Any ideas? The length of T1 and T2 is different so is the one for Y1, Y2.

Comment: can you post a sample of T1 Y1 Y2? That would make answering much easier.

Comment: Are the two tables I gave not enough? In the first file low values of T are covered (1 to 4) and it has around 70 rows. The second file covers values of T between (4 to 8); the length for this one is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

## Keeping the values of y1 and y2

Assuming you want to have a list of y1 and y2 this works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text1='''3.76    -25.8529
3.80    -25.8474
3.84    -25.8422
3.88    -25.8356
3.92    -25.8286
3.96    -25.8133
4.00    -25.7997 '''
text2 = '''3.80    -25.7331
3.84    -25.0383
3.88    -24.4059
3.92    -23.8288
3.96    -23.3027
4.00    -22.8242
4.04    -22.3917'''
f1 = {line.split()[0] : line.split()[1] for line in text1.splitlines()}
f2 = {line.split()[0] : line.split()[1] for line in text2.splitlines()}
f_total = defaultdict(list)
for key,value in f1.items():
    f_total[key].append(value)
for key,value in f2.items():
    f_total[key].append(value)
print (f_total)
```

## output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
'3.76': ['-25.8529'], 
'4.00': ['-25.7997', '-22.8242'], 
'4.04': ['-22.3917'], 
'3.80': ['-25.8474', '-25.7331'], 
'3.88': ['-25.8356', '-24.4059'], 
'3.92': ['-25.8286', '-23.8288'], 
'3.84': ['-25.8422', '-25.0383'], 
'3.96': ['-25.8133', '-23.3027']})
```

## Aggregation

If you want to just add them just change `defaultdict` type to `float`:

```
f1 = {line.split()[0] : float(line.split()[1]) for line in text1.splitlines()}
f2 = {line.split()[0] : float(line.split()[1]) for line in text2.splitlines()}
f_total = defaultdict(float)
for key,value in f1.items():
    f_total[key]+=value
for key,value in f2.items():
    f_total[key]+=value
print (f_total)
```

## output

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'4.00': -48.623900000000006, '3.96': -49.116, '3.76': -25.8529, '3.80': -51.5805, '3.92': -49.6574, '3.84': -50.8805, '4.04': -22.3917, '3.88': -50.2415})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use pandas, try the following (I am assuming your data is tab-separated).

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_table('file1.dat', names=['T','Y1'], index_col='T')
df2 = pd.read_table('file2.dat', names=['T','Y2'], index_col='T')
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).dropna()
result['Y_total'] = result.Y1 + result.Y2
print(result)
```

Using your test data, this produces the following output:

```
           Y1       Y2  Y_total
T                              
3.80 -25.8474 -25.7331 -51.5805
3.84 -25.8422 -25.0383 -50.8805
3.88 -25.8356 -24.4059 -50.2415
3.92 -25.8286 -23.8288 -49.6574
3.96 -25.8133 -23.3027 -49.1160
4.00 -25.7997 -22.8242 -48.6239
```

Finally, if you just want a DataFrame with the 'Y_total' column, use:

```
result.loc[:, ['Y_total']]
```